# Warning: Variable is unitialized in this function

Tags: c, initialization, compiler-warnings

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "scanner.h"

int WhatFell(char *typeoffood)
{
    if (strcmp(typeoffood,"meat") == 0);
    return 1;
}

void getData(char *typeoffood)
{
    printf("What fell on the floor? ");
    typeoffood = readToken(stdin);
    return;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char *typeoffood;
    int x;
    getData(typeoffood);
    x = WhatFell(typeoffood);
    printf("%s\n",typeoffood);
    printf("%d\n",x);
    return 0;
}
```

```
eat.c: In function ‘main’:
eat.c:14:12: warning: ‘typeoffood’ is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]
getData(typeoffood);
^
```

A few notes:

'readToken' is found in the "scanner.h" inclusion and simply is a safe version of scanf() for strings.
Also please just focus on the error, this is just a snippet of code I wrote seeings if I would be able to use a function getData for string input in my program.

I'm trying to use a function to ask for user string input (which I can do fine with integers/reals) and then use the string to run another function, but I keep getting all these weird warnings though and if I run it i get a segmentation fault.

Comment: `typeoffood = readToken(stdin);` means nothing to the caller of `getData`. That variable was passed by value.

Comment: Note that this function `int WhatFell(char *typeoffood)
{
    if (strcmp(typeoffood,"meat") == 0);
    return 1;
}` does not work as you intend because of the semicolon after the `if`.  Remove the spurious semicolon and it does not always return a value, a different problem.

Answer (score 4):

```
char *typeoffood;
int x;
getData(typeoffood);
```

`typeoffood` is not initialized but passed to `getData()` so would receive uninitialised data. NB: The numbers 12:14 in the message tell you the line numbers relevant to the error.

You should pass `typeoffood` as a pointer to a pointer:

```
getData(&typeoffood);
```

and give `getData()` the prototype:

```
void getData(char **);
```

Comment: Ok thanks! I got it. I knew it had to be something with pointers and addresses.